# Lazy Loading tutorial by fedor in list update problem?

Tags: android, listview

friends,

i am using following tutorial to lazy load list view

now problem is i cannot update if new data comes in any one guide me what mistake am i doing?
[Lazy Load Tutorial](http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip)

my changed code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings,mValues);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
        list.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            ChangeData();
           // adapter=new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, mStrings,mValues);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public void ChangeData()
    {
        mValues = mValues1;
        mStrings = mStrings2;

    }

 private String[] mValues = {

            "670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
            "740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
            "121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg"
 };


    private String[] mValues1 = {

            "670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
            "740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
            "121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
            "97470808/icon_normal.png",
            "511790713/AG.png",
            "956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",


    };


    private String[] mStrings ={ "http://zef.me/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/funny-cat.jpg",
            "http://www.prchurch.com/data/43_800px-Bulgaria_stub.svg.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg"};


    private String[] mStrings2={
            "http://zef.me/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/funny-cat.jpg",
            "http://www.prchurch.com/data/43_800px-Bulgaria_stub.svg.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
               };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably something like that:

```
public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        adapter.mValues = mValues1;
        adapter.mStrings = mStrings2;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: ya got it. thanks for your help :) adapter.data= mStrings1; worked!

Answer (score 0):

I believe whats happening here is that the data does not really change for the adapter.
You could add a method like this to the adapter:

```
changeData(String[] d) {

 data=d;
 notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

I think that should resolve your problem.

Cheers